# make with .cpp and .c?

Tags: c++, makefile

My Makefile keeps telling me

```
make: *** No rule to make target `rs232.c',
```

I list the files here (rs232.c is at the very end) -

```
SOURCES_RAW=codeprofiler.cpp gametimer.cpp timer.cpp timeprofile.cpp vector4.cpp matrix.cpp agent.cpp agentcontroller.cpp dummy.cpp evader.cpp pursuer.cpp goal.cpp player.cpp graphdata.cpp graph.cpp cubiccoefs.cpp segment.cpp trajectory.cpp anode.cpp arrayvector4.cpp color.cpp drawcomponent.cpp drawcontroller.cpp flags.cpp global.cpp map_analyzer.cpp minheap.cpp node.cpp quadtree.cpp queue.cpp results.cpp sensor.cpp settings.cpp utility.cpp world.cpp gui.cpp main.cpp logger.cpp parameters.cpp counter.cpp polygon.cpp line.cpp robot_driver_agent.cpp position.cpp robot_driver_priorityqueue.cpp main.cpp robot_driver_tree.cpp robot_driver_grid.cpp path.cpp tcpserver.cpp tcpclient.cpp servercontrol.cpp clientcontrol.cpp Robot.cpp udpserver.cpp udpclient.cpp rs232.c
```

All of there files are in a folder called src. So I do -

```
SRCDIR= src
SOURCES:=$(SOURCES_RAW)
SOURCES:=$(patsubst %.c, $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(SOURCES))
SOURCES:=$(patsubst %.cpp, $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp, $(SOURCES))
```

Why will it not compile the .c file?

The entire Makefile is -

```
INCLUDE = -I/usr/X11R6/include
#INCLUDE_W32 = -Isrc 
CC=g++ 
CFLAGS=-w -D LINUX -fpermissive 
CFLAGS_R= -w -D LINUX -O3 -fpermissive 
CFLAGS_D=-w -D LINUX -fpermissive 
OBJ= obj
OBJ_DEBUG= obj_debug
OBJDIR= release
SRCDIR= src

LDFLAGS= -L/usr/X11R6/lib$(LIBSELECT) -lGL -lfltk -lfltk_gl -lXext -lX11 -lglut -lGLU -lfltk_images

SOURCES_RAW=codeprofiler.cpp gametimer.cpp timer.cpp timeprofile.cpp vector4.cpp matrix.cpp agent.cpp agentcontroller.cpp dummy.cpp evader.cpp pursuer.cpp goal.cpp player.cpp graphdata.cpp graph.cpp cubiccoefs.cpp segment.cpp trajectory.cpp anode.cpp arrayvector4.cpp color.cpp drawcomponent.cpp drawcontroller.cpp flags.cpp global.cpp map_analyzer.cpp minheap.cpp node.cpp quadtree.cpp queue.cpp results.cpp sensor.cpp settings.cpp utility.cpp world.cpp gui.cpp main.cpp logger.cpp parameters.cpp counter.cpp polygon.cpp line.cpp robot_driver_agent.cpp position.cpp robot_driver_priorityqueue.cpp main.cpp robot_driver_tree.cpp robot_driver_grid.cpp path.cpp tcpserver.cpp tcpclient.cpp servercontrol.cpp clientcontrol.cpp Robot.cpp udpserver.cpp udpclient.cpp rs232.c

TARGET:= pursuit_evasion
TARGETD:= pursuit_evasion_d
TARGETP:= pursuit_evasion_p
TARGETW32:= pursuit_evasion_w32

OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES_RAW:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS:=$(patsubst %.o,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(OBJECTS))

SOURCES:=$(SOURCES_RAW)
SOURCES:=$(patsubst %.cpp, $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp, $(SOURCES))

OBJ_DEBUG:=$(SOURCES_RAW:.cpp=.o)
OBJ_DEBUG:=$(patsubst %.o,debug/%.o, $(OBJ_DEBUG))

OBJECTS_P:=$(SOURCES_RAW:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS_P:=$(patsubst %.o,profile/%.o, $(OBJECTS_P))

OBJDIR=obj

all: $(TARGET)

#--- Release 
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -w -D LINUX $(INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

release/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS_R) -o $@ 

#--- Debug
debug: $(TARGETD)

$(TARGETD): $(OBJ_DEBUG)
    $(CC) -w -D LINUX $(INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

debug/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -g $< $(CFLAGS)-o $@ 

#-- Profile
profile: $(TARGETP)

$(TARGETP): $(OBJECTS_P)
    $(CC) -w -g -pg -D LINUX $(INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

profile/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -g -pg $< $(CFLAGS)-o $@ 

win32: $(TARGETW32)

$(TARGETW32): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -w -D WIN32 $(INCLUDE_W32) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -f release/*.o
    rm -f debug/*.o
    rm -f profile/*.o
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(TARGETD) $(TARGETP)
```

Comment: You should show your rules to us, I think.

Comment: Do you have rule to compile .c files into objects?

Comment: If you list rs232.o as a prerequisite to your target, then make deduce that it needs to compile rs232.c with a C compiler.

Comment: We need to see the whole makefile.  Make is under the impression that it needs to *create* `rs232.c` for whatever reason.  Incidentally, are you aware of make's [directory search mechanism](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html)?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you only have rules for compiling files ending with `.cpp`, not with `.c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your previous files (before `rs232.c`) are actually C++ files.

I guess you have a rule to compile C++ files, later in your makefile, but do you also have a  rule to compile pure C files?

Like:

```
%.o: %.c
    gcc [...]
```

**EDIT - Just for you to know**

You're not forced to specify all the files you want to compile.

Take a look at the [`foreach`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Foreach-Function.html) and `dir` functions.
With that, you can get all files matching a specific pattern from a directory.

Example:

```
FILES = $(foreach dir,$(DIR_SRC),$(wildcard $(DIR_SRC)*.cpp))
```